# How do I make a haml-coffee closure which spans multiple lines?

Tags: syntax, coffeescript, haml, hamlc

I am trying to add a small amount of logic to one of my templates (please don't scold me on the faults of putting logic in the view) and am having a hard time getting the correct hamlc syntax.

I am iterating over a collection and want to skip elements that exist in another collection

The straight up coffeescript would look like:

```
for artwork in artworks
  unless _.find(cart_items, (ci) ->
    ci.id == artwork.product_code
      alert 'artwork not in cart'
```

I'm trying:

```
- for artwork in artworks
  - unless _.find(cart_items, (ci) -> | # < multiline, right?
    ci.id == artwork.product_code
    - alert 'artwork not in cart'
```

and am getting some hogwash about:

```
Block level too deep in line undefined
```

Any ideas?  TIA,
Billy

Comment: In the `I'm trying` section, if it a haml file, or coffeescript file? Which interpreter are you running?

Comment: Ah, right, thanks.  It's a hamlc file - https://github.com/9elements/haml-coffee.  My rep is crap so I couldnt add the hamlc tag.. ;)

Comment: I have not seen this before, thanks I'll check it out. Added the tag for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get this to work by putting the closure on the same line:

```
- for artwork in artworks
  - unless _.find(cart_items, (ci) -> ci.id == artwork.id)
    - alert 'not in the cart'
```

Comment: Haml-Coffee had a bug concerning multi-line support, which has been fixed. In addition, according to the Haml documentation, the multi line character (`|`) must also be placed on the last line.